# UFW is active but not enabled why?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I was trying to setup a firewall in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. After some struggling I got the following. Isn't this sounds a bit odd?

```
thomas@thomas-K40IJ:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
21/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
80                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

thomas@thomas-K40IJ:~$ sudo ufw reload
Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)
thomas@thomas-K40IJ:~$ sudo ufw enable 
ERROR: Could not load logging rules
thomas@thomas-K40IJ:~$
```

Also my firewall seems disabled after reboot. What am I missing?

Comment: Turning off the logging(sudo ufw logging off) solved the problem.

Comment: Use the GUFW graphical user interface for UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) it is easier...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
mateusz@debian:~$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

mateusz@debian:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive

mateusz@debian:~$ sudo ufw enable
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
```

Even if error occurs, you can check that ufw is running.

```
mateusz@debian:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

or

```
mateusz@debian:~$ sudo service ufw status
[ ok all is running...done.
```

You can easily set up manually `ENABLED=yes` in ufw config

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
```

which contains:

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=no

# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=low
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. It doesn't address the ***logical contradiction*** of the two command's output--how can the firewall be both `Status: active` & `Firewall not enabled` at the same time. And further answers suggesting using `gufw` are equally unhelpful.

Comment: @xtian This answer has the solution only at the bottom using `ENABLED=yes`. If you then run `sudo ufw enable`, it will show you `Firewall is active and enabled on system startup`. The first three steps are of no use: I had the same status before the three steps and after the three steps (SAME_STATUS --> disable -- status -- enable --> SAME_STATUS).

Answer (score 2):

Setting `ENABLED=yes` in `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` did it for me.

```
$ sudo ufw reload
Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)
$ sudo ufw logging on (showing that @Thomas' solution has no effect for me)
Logging enabled
$ sudo sed -ie 's/ENABLED=no/ENABLED=yes/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
```

Check to be sure that port 22 is enabled before you reload

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Reload

```
$ sudo ufw reload
Firewall reloaded
```

Comment: Upvote only for the nice shortcut on changing the `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` with a code line :). Yet, at `sudo ufw reload`, I get the same errors again. That is because at reload, the change of the `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` goes back to default `ENABLED=no`. The only solution up to now is to run `sudo sed -ie 's/ENABLED=no/ENABLED=yes/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf` directly before running `sudo ufw enable`.

Answer (score 0):

`ufw` has a graphical interface that could help you setup the firewall easier. It should be installed by default, but if you don't have it, do that with `sudo apt-get install gufw`.
Here is a guide on its usage https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw